# How To Catch SWF Files From Running Process Like SWF Catcher? C#

Tags: c#, process, try-catch, flash, axshockwaveflash

In the Swf Catcher Program , When I select a running process , it shows me all the flash files that are running in the process

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpjCL.png

So what i want to do , is , to make a program that catch all the swf files in the given process , like Swf Catcher , and to convert all the swf to axshockwaveflashobject and control them from there.

I tried to do it with the Process class:

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")){}
```

But I don't have access to the swf that are running in this process..
i would like to get some advice in this subject.Thanks

Comment: When you say __I don't have access to the swf that are running in this process__, what exactly did you try?

Comment: Hey , I try to get the swf file from the running process , There is a process that is running the swf file , and i want to catch the files that are running in this process , like SWF CATCHER

Comment: Yes, but **how** did you try to do that? Show the part of code in which you do that using the processes.

Comment: This is  the problem , when i create process object i don't know how to get the swf files that it is running. maybe there is any other way to do it and i dont know